# Knowing the value of tan α, how to find the angle?

Tags: algorithm, match

Knowing the value of tan α, how to find the angle?
In a right triangle, given the tangent tan α (opposite side/adjacent side), find the angle α?

I'm trying to loop through each value and compare, but I think this is different from the real data.

Comment: use `x=atan(y)` function, if not possible you can **binary search** `tan(x)` on `x=<-PI/2,+PI/2>` until it matches `y` where `x` is your angle and `y` is its `tan` note most languages and math libs use `[rad]` instead of `[deg]` units for angle so the difference might be just that...

Answer (score 2):

Every language I'm familiar with has an `arctan` function that will give you the corresponding angle for a tangent value.  If you have the actual lengths that produce the tangent (as in your triangle example) there should also be an `arctan2` function that takes both values and puts the angle in the correct quadrant.